# How to set enum value in setParameter hibernate query

Tags: hibernate

How to set enum value in setParameter hibernate  query.

```
query.setParameter( "keyValue", Enum.valueOf(, KeywordType.specific));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the enum is `KeywordType` and you want to pass the `specific` instance of this enum:

```
query.setParameter("keyValue", KeywordType.specific);
```

Just like you would use the enum anywhere else.

Comment: Weird, I need to call `toString()` to make it work  `KeywordType.specific.toString()`

Comment: @user3748908 Probably because your database table has the field datatype as varchar and not int